# python socket / how do i send datas in a row to server from client?

Tags: python, python-sockets

im having a hard time understanding how socket works.
im trying to send multiple datas to server at once or in a row.
i tried send-receive in sequence and it works but with this method, i have to send meaningless strings from server to client.
the below method also works but i have to create a new socket and close everytime..
is there a better way?

```
--------server-------------

import socket


IP = ''
PORT = 5000
SIZE = 1024
ADDR = (IP, PORT)


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind((IP, PORT)) 
    server_socket.listen()  
    print ("servers open")



    while True:
        client_socket, client_addr = server_socket.accept() 
        msg = client_socket.recv(SIZE)  
        msg = msg.decode()
        print (msg)
        client_socket.sendall("hi".encode())




----------client----------
import socket




username = 'test'
userpass = '1234'
SERVER_IP = 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT = 5000
SIZE = 1024
SERVER_ADDR = (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)




with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
    client_socket.connect(SERVER_ADDR)  


    client_socket.sendall(str(username).encode())

    client_socket.close()
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:

    client_socket.connect(SERVER_ADDR)
    client_socket.sendall(str(userpass).encode())
    #client_socket.recv(SIZE)
    #client_socket.send(b'{}'.format(abc, encoding='utf-8'))
    msg = client_socket.recv(SIZE)
    client_socket.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately your server code is broken. A correct server accepts a connection on its listening socket once for each client and then reads/writes data using the client socket as often as necessary, usually in a separate thread (one thread per client). OTOH, your server code contains this loop: wait for and accept a new connection, read from the client once, write to it once, then repeat the loop with another client. The connected client will not get another chance to communicate with the server. I recommend to read some tutorial or study examples in the docs.